# Switch to at Iframe in selenium java

Tags: selenium, iframe, switch-statement

I am new using selenium and I am trying to test a web page. This page has as iframe and for the read I need do a switch, the switch I did was:
    wait.until(ExpectedConditions.frameToBeAvailableAndSwitchToIt(frame));
But it does not works, maybe somebody should be help me? Here is my code. this code of my page:

```
public class MainPage extends BasePageObject{
    @FindBy(id = "cc-sa-item-logo")
    WebElement iconLogin;
    private  By frame = By.xpath("//iframe[@id='cms']");

    public MainPage() {
        PageFactory.initElements(driver, this);
        waitUntilPageObjectIsLoaded();
    }

    @Override
    public void waitUntilPageObjectIsLoaded() {
        wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOf(iconLogin));
    }

    public boolean logOutExists() {
        boolean res = true;
        String parentWindow = driver.getWindowHandle();
        try{            wait.until(ExpectedConditions.frameToBeAvailableAndSwitchToIt(frame));
            res = iconLogin.isDisplayed();
        }finally {
            driver.switchTo().window(parentWindow);
        }
        return res;
    }
```

and this is the code of page the test:

```
<iframe id="cms" class="cms" src="/app/s9cea6fcedc36dd82/p430c9b54081c966d/" onload="this.loaded = true;" name="cms">
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es-ES">
<head>
<body id="page-2281940529" class="body cc-page cc-page-index cc-indexpage j-m-flash-styles j-m-gallery-styles j-m-video-styles j-m-hr-styles j-m-header-styles j-m-text-styles j-m-emotionheader-styles j-m-htmlCode-styles j-m-rss-styles j-m-form-styles-disabled j-m-table-styles j-m-textWithImage-styles j-m-downloadDocument-styles j-m-imageSubtitle-styles j-m-flickr-styles j-m-googlemaps-styles j-m-blogSelection-styles-disabled j-m-comment-styles j-m-jimdo-styles j-m-profile-styles j-m-guestbook-styles j-m-promotion-styles j-m-twitter-styles j-m-hgrid-styles j-m-shoppingcart-styles j-m-catalog-styles j-m-product-styles-disabled j-m-facebook-styles j-m-sharebuttons-styles j-m-externalSource-styles j-m-formnew-styles-disabled j-m-callToAction-styles j-m-turbo-styles j-m-spacing-styles j-m-googleplus-styles j-m-dummy-styles j-footer-styles cc-content-parent" style="background-position: -186px 0px;">
<div class="cc-bs cc-alert-container" ng-controller="cms.common.AlertCtrl"> </div>
<div id="cc-eh" data-display="cms-only">
<div id="cc-nav" class="cc-jimdo ui-draggable" data-display="cms-only">
<script>
<div id="cc-clipboard" class="cc-clipboard-scrolled-left cc-clipboard-scrolled-right cc-clipboard-empty" data-display="cms-only" style="right: 186px; display: block;">
<div id="cc-inner" class="cc-content-parent" style="padding-right: 186px; padding-top: 0px;">
<div id="cc-sa" data-display="cms-only" style="display: block;">
<div id="cc-sa-sidebar" ng-controller="cms.sa.SidebarCtrl">
<div class="cc-sa-sidebar-group cc-sa-sidebar-group--top">
<div class="cc-sa-sidebar-logo-open clear">
<span id="cc-sa-item-logo" class="cc-sa-sidebar-logo" data-params="/app/siteadmin/upgrade/index/,true" data-action="sidebarItem"> </span>
```

I need find the element of span tag

Answer (score 0):

The issue here is that the first thing you do, after initializing the FindBy-annotated fields, is `waitUntilPageObjectIsLoaded`, which is implicitly calling `driver.findElement(By.id("cc-sa-item-logo"))`.
And here it fails, as you haven't switched to the frame yet at this point, and unfortunately PageFactory is not able to handle that.

Basically you need to wrap each and every call to a FindBy-annotated field with a `switchTo().frame`/`switchTo().defaultContent()`. Just like you did in `logOutExists`.

For convenience, I would model the iframe in a separate page object (class), so as to encapsulate (and automate) the switching back and forth.

```
public class CmsIframe extends BasePageObject implements AutoCloseable {

    @FindBy(id = "cc-sa-item-logo")
    WebElement iconLogin;

    private  By frame = By.xpath("//iframe[@id='cms']");

    public CmsIframe() {
        wait.until(ExpectedConditions.frameToBeAvailableAndSwitchToIt(frame));
        PageFactory.initElements(driver, this);
        waitUntilPageObjectIsLoaded();
    }

    @Override
    public void waitUntilPageObjectIsLoaded() {
        wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOf(iconLogin));
    }

    public boolean logOutExists() {
        return iconLogin.isDisplayed();
    }

    @Override
    public void close() {
        driver.switchTo().defaultContent();
    }

}
```

MainPage can then be re-written as follows:

```
public class MainPage extends BasePageObject{
    private  By frame = By.xpath("//iframe[@id='cms']");

    public MainPage() {
        PageFactory.initElements(driver, this);
    }


    public boolean logOutExists() {
        try (CmsIframe cmsIframe = new CmsIframe()) {
            return cmsIframe.logOutExists();
        } // when exiting this try block, the driver will automatically be switched back out of the iframe (as part of CmsIframe#close)
    }
}
```

Please note that thanks to `implements AutoCloseable`, CmsIframe can be used in a [try-with-resources Statement](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html) (java > 7 only), which sorts of automates the switching back to the default content.

PS: if you could post the stacktrace with the exception you are getting, that would help help you.

Comment: I tried implement the solution that suggest but the result is the same. the message error is: Element info: {Using=id, value=logout}
  at sun.reflect.GeneratedConstructorAccessor10.newInstance(Unknown Source)
  at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
  at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:422)

Answer (score 0):

I finally solved my problem, you had reason the problem was that I find the switch in the place incorrect. the solution was:

```
 @Override
    public void waitUntilPageObjectIsLoaded() {
        String parentWindow = driver.getWindowHandle();
        try{
            wait.until(ExpectedConditions.frameToBeAvailableAndSwitchToIt(frame));
            wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOf(iconLogin));
        }finally {
            driver.switchTo().window(parentWindow);
        }
    }

    public boolean logOutExists() {
        boolean res = true;
        String parentWindow = driver.getWindowHandle();
        try{
            wait.until(ExpectedConditions.frameToBeAvailableAndSwitchToIt(frame));
            res = iconLogin.isDisplayed();
        }finally {
            driver.switchTo().window(parentWindow);
        }
        return res;
    }
```